# How to configure BOSH server to support my own XMPP server?

Tags: xmpp, converse.js

I set up a BOSH server using [node-xmpp-bosh](https://github.com/dhruvbird/node-xmpp-bosh/) and configured [converse.js](https://conversejs.org/) (a javascript XMPP client) to use the BOSH url I set up, I tried log in with my jabber.org account on converse.js and all worked fine.

Now I need to make this work with a private XMPP server.  Assume that the XMPP server is at chat.mysite.com:5222, a JID on the server is johndoe@mysite.com. How do I configure the BOSH server so that it connects to chat.mysite.com:5222 when I try to log in with johndoe@mysite.com on converse.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add [DNS SRV](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/SRV_Records) record `_xmpp-client._tcp.mysite.com` which should point to chat.mysite.com 5222